# Retrieve with ws proxy with filter using DateValue does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, wsproxy

Hello dear sfmc people,

using date field in filter does not work as it's stated in the documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/simplefilterpart.html

I have filter

```
var filter = {
Property: "LastRunTime",
SimpleOperator: "greaterThanOrEqual",
DateValue: '2022-06-01T01:00:00.000Z'
};
```

Function that retrieves automation, I did use the example from
https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/automation-studio/automations/retrieve/all.html

Anybody got luck retrieve objects by filtering date values?

I will do workaround, that i have in mind if there is no solution to this.

Comment: Did you try using a Date data type for the value instead of a String?

Comment: Hello @AdamSpriggs thanks for stopping by. it throws exactly the same error.

```{"message":"Error executing retrieve call.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Error executing retrieve call.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}```

Comment: `LastRunTime` isn't a retrievable property on the [Automation SOAP object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/automation.html).  It's not listed in the official docs at all, but if you do a Describle on the object, you'll find its `IsRetrievable` value is `false`.  That'll keep you from filtering on it.

Comment: I generally retrieve Program via SOAP to get the ObjectID and then REST to retrieve the Automation details.  From there you can get the AutomationInstance details via REST using LastRunInstanceId.

Comment: Yes, I have workaround to get this list, but it would be great to learn how to set up filter on date field :) 

My goal is to get list of automations that run in the last 6months. My workaround is to get full list and then filter down on the last run field in automation

I have logged ticket with support perhaps when they come back will provide their answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/automation.html) you can only use EQUALS and IN as simple operator

> The only supported operators for the Automation object are: IN,
> EQUALS. Complex filter is not supported.